# Как решить проблему с Bootstrap?

Tags: html5

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста. При использовании Bootstrap 3.3.7 в Chrome вылезает ошибка:

Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'U5ZEeKfGNOja007MMD3YBI0A3OSZOQbeG6z2f2Y0hu8='. The resource has been blocked.

Кто знает как исправить?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <title>Bootstrap</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
      
        <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse">
          <div class="container">

            <div class="navbar-header header">

              <div class="container">

                <div class="row">

                  <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1><a href=""></a></h1>
                    <p></p>
                  </div>

                </div>

              </div>

              <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">

                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                </button> 

            </div>

            <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">

              <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"></a></li>
              </ul>

            </div>

          </div>

        </nav>

      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ошибка только в google?

Comment: возможно неправильно подключил боотстрап

Comment: не проверил версию 3.3.7 но с новой версией у меня все сработало хотя изначально появилась та же ошибка и сама же исчезла смени  версию если не обязательно 3.3.7 по ошибке нечего сказать не магу сам не разобрался

Answer (score 0):

Возможно кому-то помогу.
Эта ошибка связана с Subresource Integrity. Предположу, что на тот момент не был обновлен хэш у cdn, либо ваш dns был скомпрометирован.
Подробности здесь https://blog.daniil-solovyev.ru/posts/3